# Margin between 2 Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i'm trying to add a top and bottom margin to all my PackageCells.
like [image: Cells need space between eachother]

what ive tried

```
  %hook PackageCell
-(void)didMoveToWindow {

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    %orig;
}
-(CGRect)frame {
    CGRect r = %orig;
    return CGRectMake(40, 0, r.size.width, r.origin.height+20);
}
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CGRect r = frame;
      %orig(CGRectMake(40, 0, r.size.width, r.origin.height+20));
}

%end
```

All cells get stacked on top of eachother and look weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `backgroundColor` of the cell to `[UIColor clear]`

And Change the frames of the contentView instead and make that view round

```
self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
```

And update the frame for this

```
self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.origin.height+20);
```